# 2-column HTML layout for printed document

Tags: html, css, printing, weasyprint

I want to create a document for print/PDF with multiple chapters. Each chapter has a two-column layout, but the header of a chapter spans both columns. I use [`weasyprint`](https://weasyprint.org/) to generate the PDF. My current approach uses the `flex` layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
@page {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    size: A4;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Ubuntu Condensed", sans-serif;
}

header {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}

div.column {
    display: flex;
}

main {
    flex: 1;
}

aside {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #eee;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<article>
    <header>
        <h1>Chapter 1</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="column">
        <main>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis neque ac quam eleifend venenatis id sit amet erat. Cras pellentesque diam lorem, quis dignissim velit rutrum sit amet. Suspendisse potenti. Suspendisse lobortis et tellus a tempus. Suspendisse eget justo erat. Morbi euismod ligula a justo bibendum, at volutpat velit lobortis. Sed ut enim felis. Integer a maximus leo. 
        </main>
        <aside>
             Phasellus in libero dictum, vestibulum dui quis, elementum felis. Sed luctus, ligula sit amet vulputate faucibus, arcu nunc molestie justo, ac porta ipsum nulla vel erat. Morbi vel sem odio. Morbi lobortis dui condimentum elit tempor, at fringilla nisl pulvinar. Phasellus id enim eget urna porttitor congue in eu turpis. Duis vel rhoncus mi. Nam nec mauris finibus, scelerisque orci tempus, rhoncus massa. Proin suscipit lectus in ex maximus facilisis. 
        </aside>
    </div>
</article>
<article>
    <header>
        <h1>Chapter 2</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="column">
        <main>
             Nullam sagittis gravida est quis rutrum. Mauris vestibulum sapien non pellentesque laoreet. Vestibulum blandit metus vitae lectus sagittis eleifend. Vestibulum odio mi, fermentum convallis commodo nec, dapibus id justo. Integer finibus commodo dolor, congue mollis dui iaculis sed. Quisque ut metus sollicitudin, ullamcorper ipsum id, hendrerit ligula. Donec ut viverra lacus. Nullam ultricies faucibus nisl ac consequat. Duis in nisl facilisis, fermentum velit fringilla, sollicitudin ipsum. Sed pretium enim et turpis pulvinar, vel maximus tortor laoreet. Vivamus rhoncus, mauris quis accumsan sodales, lacus metus suscipit felis, maximus aliquam sapien urna eu libero. Cras nec volutpat metus. 
        </main>
        <aside>
             Vestibulum at elementum velit. Nunc sollicitudin nibh quis sagittis facilisis. Phasellus eget pellentesque ligula. Curabitur condimentum non massa a sollicitudin. Fusce pulvinar elit vitae dui euismod commodo. Curabitur fermentum velit at ex rutrum pretium. Proin nec purus dictum, viverra arcu a, viverra eros. Etiam malesuada auctor purus, ut posuere erat finibus vitae. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Donec in elit nulla. Nam hendrerit, libero ut feugiat pretium, tortor nibh finibus nulla, nec volutpat erat dui eget dolor. Vestibulum urna lorem, euismod eget scelerisque sed, mattis eget diam. 
        </aside>
    </div>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem with this approach is that I have to re-define `<div class="column">` in every chapter. `weasyprint` apparently doesn't support grid layout. The drawback of the [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) layout is that I have to specify the width of both the left and right column, but I'd prefer to specify the width of the side column and let the main column take up the rest space.

1. Is there a better solution to this problem?
2. Is there an alternative to `weasyprint` that supports grid layout?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can solve your problem by using **flex-shrink**. You can use this css

> ```
>  aside {
>     width: 350px;
>     background-color: #eee;
>     flex-shrink: 0;
>  }
> ```

2. For print purpose you can also use [jQuery.print](https://doersguild.github.io/jQuery.print/)

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on how I should use `flex-shrink`? When I remove `<div class="column">` from the HTML, where should I put the `display: flex` then?

Comment: You will find better explanation here [understanding flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis](https://css-tricks.com/understanding-flex-grow-flex-shrink-and-flex-basis/)

Comment: I already looked up flex-shrink. `flex-shrink: 0` avoids that the side bar shrinks. But I'll still need the parent element, right? So, I'm not clear how this solves my problem.